# How I can turn this function into an async await function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

Using: MongoDB, Express, Mongoose, NodeJs.

I currently have a seedDB function which takes an array of months and seeds a 'months' collection. This looks like so:

```
const monthData = [{
        month: 'January',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'February',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'March',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'April',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'May',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'June',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'July',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'August',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'September',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'October',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'November',
        shifts: []
    },
    {
        month: 'December',
        shifts: []
    }
];

function seedDB() {
    for (entry of monthData) {
        Month.create(entry, (err, created) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else console.log(created);
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need the the months to seed in order (which doesn't always happen using this method) so I feel like an async function might work here, something that tells it only to advance to creating the next month when the previous month has been seeded.

I have watched countless tutorials on promises and async await and I still don't fully understand how to apply the logic. I'd appreciate if someone could show and explain an async/promise alternative to my current code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two additions. An `async` keyword in front of the `seedDB` function, and an `await` kayword in front of each Promise:

```
async function seedDB() {
    for (entry of monthData) {
        await Month.create(entry, (err, created) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else console.log(created);
        })
    }
}
```

The `for` loop will now not continue until each individual Promise resolves.

**EDIT**: Since it's possible that `Month.create()` doesn't return a Promise (it looks like a traditional err/value callback, you may need to wrap it in a Promise manually like so:

```
async function seedDB() {
    for (entry of monthData) {
        await new Promise((resolvePromise, rejectPromise) =>
            Month.create(entry, (err, created) => {
                if (err) {
                    rejectPromise();
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    resolvePromise();
                    console.log(created);
                }
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using Node you may be able to take advantage of [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) -- which takes callback-style functions and returns a function that provides a regular promise.

```
const util = require('util');
const createMonthPromise = util.promisify(Month.create);

async function seedDB() {
    for (entry of monthData) {
        const created = await createMonthPromise(entry);
        console.log('Created!', created);
    }
}
```

**[More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)**:

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a Promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected), and to resume execution of the async function after fulfillment. When resumed, the value of the await expression is that of the fulfilled Promise.

Comment: Thankyou, looks like exactly what I wanted however it doesn't seem to make a difference...? The months are still being input in any order

Comment: That works perfectly, thankyou! Just seeing that block of code has made it click!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.mapSeries from 'bluebird' library

In this article you can see examples and explanation
https://medium.com/@ekeyur/bluebirds-map-and-mapseries-explained-by-cooking-pasta-7dd03a19ea61

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

   function seedDB() {
        return Promise.mapSeries(monthData, (month) => {
            return Month.create(month)
        });
   }

   async function test() {
        const result = await seedDB();
   }
```

But I would not recommend you store records in db with order dependency. Review your schema and use cases , maybe you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe can you use "create" callback to make sure the previous entry was created this way:

```
let i=0;
let callback = ()=> {if (i< monthData.length){ seedDB(i); console.log(i, "seeded"); i++;} }

function seedDB(index){
    Month.create(monthData[index], callback)    
}
```